TypeScript does not pick up the correct function overload
Given the following function implementation:
function fmap<T, U>(value: T, f: (x: T) => U): U;
function fmap<T, U>(value: T | undefined, f: (x: T) => U): U | undefined;
function fmap<T, U>(value: T | null, f: (x: T) => U): U | null;
function fmap<T, U>(value: T | null | undefined, f: (x: T) => U): U | null | undefined {
    return value === undefined ? undefined : value === null ? null : f(value);
}

I get the correct types in the following cases:
const test1 = (v: string) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string
const test2 = (v: string | null) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | null
const test3 = (v: string | undefined) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | undefined
const test4 = (v: string | null | undefined) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | null | undefined
const test5 = (v: string) => fmap(v, x => 1); // ✅ expected: number

But not in these cases:
// ❌ expected: number | null (actual: number)
const test6 = (v: string | null) => fmap(v, x => 1);

// ❌ expected: number | undefined (actual: number)
const test7 = (v: string | undefined) => fmap(v, x => 1);

// ❌ expected: number | null | undefined (actual: number)
const test8 = (v: string | null | undefined) => fmap(v, x => 1);

See Playground

Removed my answer. It is obvious to me why the first one matches though and I think the solution might be to use NonNullable, but I don't see it right away and I don't have the time to investigate further.

I don't get it, the U generic type is inferred from f's return type, since f returns a number in test6, U is inferred as a number, it's the expected value, not number | null.

@HairyHandKerchief23 According to the implementation, f is invoked only if the value is non nullable. In other words, test6 will return null in case v is not defined. Hence, your assumption is incorrect.

I mean, T is inferred as string | undefined instead of string, so it's always using the first overload

I found a way to do it without overloads : check this

Impressive! post as an answer so I could mark it as the correct answer.

@Silvermind you were very close as well, you just had to add an additional overload: https://tsplay.dev/NDjr8W, restore your answer as well for an upvote.

You'll need to extract nullable types from T generic type
type ExtractedNullable<T> = Extract<T, null | undefined>

function fmap<T, U>(value: T, f: (x: T) => U): U | ExtractedNullable<T> {
    return value === undefined ? undefined as ExtractedNullable<T> : value === null ? null as ExtractedNullable<T> : f(value);
}

const test1 = (v: string) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string
const test2 = (v: string | null) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | null
const test3 = (v: string | undefined) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | undefined
const test4 = (v: string | null | undefined) => fmap(v, x => x); // ✅ expected: string | null | undefined
const test5 = (v: string) => fmap(v, x => 1); // ✅ expected: number

const test6 = (v: string | null) => fmap(v, x => 1); // number | null

const test7 = (v: string | undefined) => fmap(v, x => 1); // number | undefined

const test8 = (v: string | null | undefined) => fmap(v, x => 1); // number | null | undefined 

